# sklearn.linear_model.LassoCV Hard-Sets "precompute" to False Before Final Fit

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

I'm using a very large data-set. After fitting 100 x 3-fold cross-validated LASSOs at lightning speed, LassoCV stalls at the final hurdle: fitting a LASSO with the chosen alpha value to the whole data-set. After a lot of head-scratching I found the reason why. In coordinate_descent.py's LinearModelCV.fit() just before calling the final model.fit() (line 1223 in Python2.7/sklearn0.19.0), there is the rather inconspicuous line

```
model.precompute = False
```

So even if you've specified precompute as True when calling LassoCV, it is ignored. Why is this? It's making the computation impractically slow, and literally just commenting the line out fixes it. Am I missing something here, I can't see anything wrong with using a precomputed Gram matrix for the final fit when it was used for all of the cross-validation fits? The implementation seems to imply it should be used whenever num_samples > num_features. Why hard set it to False?